# How to find elements in a list is consecutive

Tags: python, list

Hi I have a list `[tag1 tag2]`, I would like to find out whether the number following tag is incremental.

```
match_atr_value = re.search('(.+)\~(\w+)',each_line)
tags = match_atr_value.group(1).split('.')
print tag


Input: 
[tag1 tag2]
[tag1 tag3]
[tag1 tag2 tag4]

Output:
Incremental
Not
Not
```

"Consecutive integers are integers that follow each other in order"

Is there a simpler way to do it? All I have to do is check if its incremental and if yes I should use them else I should throw an exception. 
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by consecutive?

Comment: There are two independent issues here. Extracting the numbers, and checking if a list of numbers is consecutive. Which one are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract all the digits followed by `tag` via [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) and then use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) to check if the numbers are consecutive:

```
import re

l = [
    "[tag1 tag2]",
    "[tag1 tag3]",
    "[tag1 tag2 tag4]"
]

pattern = re.compile(r"tag(\d+)")
for item in l:
    numbers = map(int, pattern.findall(item))  # if Python 3: call list() on that
    result = all(index == item for index, item in enumerate(numbers, start=numbers[0]))
    print(result)
```

Prints:

```
True
False
False
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would avoid a regex and do something like below. I get the number from the string, whether it's beginning, end, etc. and then compare it to the previous value and `return False` if it's not increasing

```
def isIncreasing( listy ):
        prev = 0
        for w in listy:
                val = [''.join(s) for s in w if s.isdigit()]
                cur = int(val[0])
                if cur != prev+1:
                        return False
                prev = cur
        return True
```

Comment: I had to use the reg ex as I need `re.search('(.+)\~(\w+)'` to have the value in the second group as well. I had asked a question to solve the results of a first group. Thanks

Comment: I think "increasing" and "consecutive" are different things.

Comment: Edited to be **consecutive**

Answer (score 0):

```
tag1val = int(re.search(r'\D*(\d+)', tag1).group(1))
tag2val = int(re.search(r'\D*(\d+)', tag2).group(1))
(tag1val - tag2val) == -1
  True
tag3val = int(re.search(r'\D*(\d+)', tag3).group(1))
(tag1val - tag3val) == -1
  False
(tag2val - tag3val) == -1
  True
```

If you wanted to stick with regular expressions, you can go this route. If the difference is -1 then the one on the right is 1 greater than the one on the left.

Comment: Please don't use `is` when checking for equality. It's not guaranteed that `-1 is -1` evaluates to True. (it almost certainly does for most sane implementations of Python, but it's not something you should depend on)